# How can you tell when the game is saving data?

Tags: worms-2-armageddon

When I'm playing Worms 2: Armageddon, I don't know when it's saving data (Shop, teams, stuff). Is it when the Armageddon sign is on-screen?

Comment: So it's not Worms 2, and it's not Worms Armageddon. What a confusing name.